# Email to be sent to reviewer when a developer checks-in code in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, checkin

In TFS, when a developer checks-in the code, an email is sent to his reviewer. Only after the reviewer approves, can the developer or reviewer himself check-in the code. Is this possible ? Can someone please help me with the steps to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, but with an add-in from a guy called Colin. http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/custom-code-review-checkin-policy

With this extension, you can set the Check-in policy to state that there must be a linked completed code review with no "Needs Work" rejections.

This will mean that a developer must request a review based on pending changes and wait for this to be reviewed and then close the review, before attempting a check-in.

Developers can still override the check-in policy and bypass this but you can create a subscription each time the policy is overridden so you can receive an email about it.

We have been using this add-on for some time now and it mostly works as expected.